# Mockito.any in Jest

Tags: typescript, jestjs

Is there a equivalent for mockito.any in jest? I have a function with the signature:

```
postStampService = async (
  req: functions.https.Request,
  res: functions.Response<any>,
  admin: any,
  defaultFirestore: Firestore
)
```

This function calls another function. My Test looks like this:

```
jest.mock("../authentication/utils", () => {
  const original = jest.requireActual("../authentication/utils");
  return {
    ...original,
    checkAuthHeader: jest.fn(),
  };
});

it("should call checkAuthHeader", async () => {
  try {
    postStampService()
  } catch (error) {
    expect(checkAuthHeader).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }
});
```

How can I test this the best way? How can I mock the function parameters of postStampService?